# LItespeed ESI Hole punching in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: caching, browser, prestashop-1.6, litespeed

Is there any way where we can use the ESI hole punching in Prestashop 1.6.

Here they have explained how to do for 1.7 using widget block
https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:cache:lscps:customization_1_7

I want to do it for 1.6 
Have anyone done it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no way to punch hole in Prestashop 1.6.

I have resolved by taking some actions.

If someone faces same issue you need to do to this:

In module configuration set "Separate Cache Copy per Customer Group" to "Two View - One for logged in users and another for logged out users"

In .htaccess

add

```
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days" 
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 minutes"
```

to

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
```

Remember to Flush the pages and wait for some time and the cache takes some time.

It will be helpful to test in a private window of the browser.
Hope it helps!

Note: If changes are not appearing on prestashop then uninstall the module.